# Transforming XML by means of XSLT — how to remove tags totally?

Tags: xml, xslt

At this moment, I working with XSLT & need help. I have this XML file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="no"?>
<entries>
    <entry>
        <field>1</field>
    </entry>
    <entry>
        <field>2</field>
    </entry>
    <entry>
        <field>3</field>
    </entry>
    <entry>
        <field>4</field>
    </entry>
    <entry>
        <field>5</field>
    </entry>
</entries>
```

I need to format this XML to reseive this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="no"?>
<entries>
    <entry field="1">
    <entry field="2">
    <entry field="3">
    <entry field="4">
    <entry field="5">
</entries>
```

But I reseive this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="no"?><entries>

        <entry field="1">


        <entry field="2">


        <entry field="3">


        <entry field="4">


        <entry field="5">

</entries>
```

XSLT-file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" version="3.0">
    <xsl:output method="xml" indent="no" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="no"/>
    <xsl:template match="entries">
        <entries>
            <xsl:apply-templates/>
        </entries>
    </xsl:template>
    <xsl:template match="entry">
            <xsl:apply-templates/>
    </xsl:template>
    <xsl:template match="field">
        <xsl:text disable-output-escaping="yes">&lt;entry field="</xsl:text><xsl:apply-templates/><xsl:text disable-output-escaping="yes">"&gt;</xsl:text>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

As we see, `XSLT-stylesheet` simply deletes tags, without removing them, leaving space. How to remove tags `<entry>` totally & move first `<entries>` tag to the next line? Otherwise, how to make XML to the desired form?

Comment: Why do you want to put an XML declaration in the output when it clearly isn't XML? Who are you trying to confuse?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you really must output ill-formed XML (i.e. not an XML document at all), then I would suggest you use `text` as the output method and format the indents yourself:

**XSLT 1.0**

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" 
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:output method="text"/>
<xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

<xsl:template match="entries">
    <xsl:text>&lt;entries></xsl:text>
        <xsl:apply-templates/>
    <xsl:text>&#10;&lt;/entries></xsl:text>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="entry">
    <xsl:text>&#10;    &lt;entry field="</xsl:text>
    <xsl:value-of select="field"/>
    <xsl:text>"></xsl:text>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: Looks great, but how to remove slash there: <entry field="{field}"/> & how to save indents before tags?

Comment: @ВячеславЧернышов  Are you really trying to output open tags without closing them? What would be the purpose of that?

Comment: Ufortunately, this is technical task. Is it possible?

Comment: It's not possible to preserve the indents before tags AND at the same time not to preserve the line feeds that are in the same whitespace-only nodes. But you *can* insert your own indents.

Comment: Please, tell me how to insert my own whitespaces & indents in document using one of your examples.